# Why does MongoDB $lt query return documents that don't include the fields being queried?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of items of the form:

```
{ 
    # random fields here
    events: [
        ... 
        { 
            # random fields here...
            last_update_submitted: some date
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to query the collection to find all documents where the final event in the array of *events* has a *last_update_submitted* date of more than 30 days ago. So far, I've written this aggregation query:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      events: "$events",
      last_event: {
        $last: "$events",
      },
      thirty_days_ago: {
        $dateSubtract: {
          startDate: new ISODate(),
          unit: "day",
          amount: 30
        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$last_event.last_update_submitted",
          "$thirty_days_ago"
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

The problem is that the query returns not only the documents that have a last event which matches the criteria, but also documents with a last event that don't include the *last_update_submitted* field at all. So in my example, if the *last_update_submitted* date is more than 30 days ago, it is rightfully returned. If the date is less then 30 days ago, it is rightfully excluded. But even if the last event doesn't include the *last_update_submitted* field at all, it is returned as well.

Is this behavior expected? And if so, what is the recommended way for dealing with this? Should I check for the field existence first?

Comment: Redirecting a bit - is there any particular reason that you've structured the aggregation this way? In particular you are currently adding the comparison field to the doc which then forces your usage of $expr in the subsequent $match  stage. But since the comparison doesn't have anything to do with data in the document, you could forego adding the field and using $expr and instead do a 'standard' comparison in the $match directly. I suspect this is an alternate way to fix your problem (due to semantic differences between the two) approaches

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that hilights the power of `$ifNull` and setting variables with `$let` so that the evaluation can happen just once.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        X: {$let: {
            vars: {
                e:{$last:'$events'},
                t:'$$NOW'  // capture point in time                              
            },
            in: {$cond: [
                // IF last_update_submitted is null OR ABSENT, call the value    
                // $$NOW which clearly is NOT more than 30 days ago:             
                {$lt:[ {$ifNull:["$$e.last_update_submitted","$$t"]},
                       {$dateSubtract: {startDate: '$$t', unit: "day",amount: 30}} ]},

                // THEN if older than 30 days, emit the whole object:      
                "$$e",

                // ELSE emit null                                                
                null
            ]}
        }}
    }},

    //  Exclude all the nulls:                                                   
    {$match: {X: {$ne: null}}}
]);
```